# Hotlinking to reduce bandwidth usage?

Tags: bandwidth, hotlinking

I manage two websites for a client, each hosted with a different company. One site is an eCommerce site and the other is a blog for the eCommerce site.

The eCommerce site is reaching its bandwidth limits (25GB/month), while the blog has plenty of room.

Would moving the product images from the eCommerce server to the blog server be a legitimate solution to relieving the bandwidth strain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. As long as the ecommerce server has the bandwidth available and can handle the load this would work just fine. If the ecommerce server cannot handle the load you may want to consider an affordable CDN like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) where you only pay for what you use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Would SEO be affected as a result of the images not being hosted on the same domain as the eCommerce site?

Comment: @Michael: There is no problem for SEO to use CDN, it's even recommended.